# Is Delphi 10 valid for life or only for a year?

Tags: delphi

I downloaded the free version of Delphi 10 "Community Editor", and I heard that the license is valid for a year, and some say for a month, and some say it is valid for life but You only have to request the key-license again, is that correct? Because I want to work on it for life, and I don't want it to stop working after a year and my projects to be lost and my efforts to be wasted. Do you recommend it to me, or do I work on Delphi 7, which I downloaded for free for life?

Also, I have two versions of the Delphi program 7 and 10, will there be interference between them and cause problems and burden the computer?

Comment: The community edition is for a year. The trial is for a month. Whether or not you continue to use Delphi 7, or Delphi 11.3 will depend on what you want to use it for

Comment: Note the [FAQ](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/faq) covers it in question 20. What is the term of the Community Edition license?

Comment: As far as I know Delphi 7 has never been free. Delphi Community Edition is free for non commercial use and also for small commercial use limited to revenue up to 5000$ per year. The registration work for 1 year but you can request a renewal each year. All this is explained in details at Embarcadero website. If you need a life time license then you have to buy it.

Comment: There was a free Delphi 7 Personal Edition, was even included on some UK Magazine cover CDs and was downloadable from the Borland site.

Comment: Different Delphi versions installed simultaneously on a system normal don't effect each other.

Comment: Indeed, personal versions of Delphi 4 and 7, at least, were included on magazine CDs in Sweden too.

Comment: Also have at look at the free and open source Object Pascal IDE Lazarus, if you don't like the Delphi license model.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question. Contact the vendor directly for questions regarding the licensing terms of their product. This site is for programming related questions only..